# ¿Como soluciono Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at?

Tags: java, excepciones, null, interfaz

necesito ayuda con una interfaz, quiero registrar materiales en otra ventana llamada listas pero al escribirlos y presionar guardar me marca estos errores. Adjunto mi código. Quiero que se guarde en otra ventana llamada listas que funciona como archivos en Java.
[image: interfaz]

public class Acciones {

```
private static Materiales formulario;
private static RegMateriales material [];
private static int contador;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    formulario=new Materiales();
    material=new RegMateriales[100];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        material [i]= new RegMateriales();
        
        
    }
    contador = 0;
    
    formulario.setVisible(true);
}

public static void guardar(String n, int e, Double t, String m, Double p, String c, int cb)
{
  material[contador].setNombre(m);
  material[contador].setExistencias(cb);
  material[contador].setTamañoCM(0); 
  material[contador].setMarca(c);
  material[contador].setPrecio(p); 
  material[contador].setColor(c); 
  material[contador].setCodigoDeBarras(contador);
  
  contador++;
  
}
```

}

[image: Error]

Comment: Cual es la linea 35 de Acciones.java ?

Comment: Material[contador].set nombre